# TextBlock and TextBox objects alignment depending on width of border container

Tags: wpf

What I have when size of Border container is wide enough:

TextBlock TextBox TextBlock TextBox

then size of Border gets smaller and I have something like this:

TextBlock TextBox TextBlock Tex

there is not enough space for the fourth TextBox so what I need is something like this:

TextBlock TextBox
TextBlock TextBox

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WrapPanel` + container around units.